# Realm database in ionic project

Tags: ionic-framework, mobile, realm

I'm creating a project with **IONIC FRAMEWORK** and I wish I knew if it is possible to use `Realm database`.

 Any answer and documentation will be hepful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you referred the Realm documentation on their github page ? Only supports React Native and Node as of now.

Comment: Not yet. Thanks for your answer.